# Software Serial in avr

Tags: arduino, avr

I need two RX and two TX pin in my program.
In arduino with "SoftwareSerial" easily I can make several RX and TX.
how to make it in avr(make two rx and two tx port)?¿?

Comment: The Arduino SoftwareSerial library is designed to run on AVRs, so you can probably compile it and run it on your AVR.  If you encounter a specific problem when doing that, you can post a specific question with a bit of code and the error message you are getting.

Comment: when I write (#include <SoftwareSerial.h> ) in CV AVR an error is happen. error is ( can't open #include file: SoftwareSerial.h )

Comment: Just use timers and GPIO ports to generate the signal. Or just use a part with two USARTs

Comment: To fix errors involving your compiler finding header files, you must move the header file into a directory that the compiler will search in, or add include directories to the command line using GCC's `-I` option.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways for you:

1. Add `#include` path for g++ (must be c++ since `Serial` is a class).
   Then just include the header as you did in Arduino.
2. Refer to [AVR306](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-1451-Using-the-AVR-USART-on-tinyAVR-and-megaAVR-devices_ApplicationNote_AVR306.pdf) and device datasheet (I don't know what your MCU is) to learn how to use USART.

The first is easier and more convenient while the second is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend including the Arduino libraries and just including SoftwareSerial as a one of your libraries because the pins_arduino.h file will take care of the mapping for you. However if you don't have the right pins_arduino.h for your AVR I would recommend looking into this git I made for this issue. I adjusted a lot of the code from SoftwareSerial.

https://github.com/joshagirgis/AVRonly-adjustedRecieveOnlySoftwareSerial

My issue was I wanted to use an atmega644pa with a software serial port but only receive the data. Note: it is much harder to read the data, software serially, than send it (bit banging). I had it receive only because I only needed to read commands from a GPS. The pin must be an interrupt pin.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pins that have interrupt capability and since in atmega mcu there is no pinChangeInterrupt so you should use pins that have simple interrupts like 10 and 11 on atmega16/32 for RX pin and any digital pin for TX.